# Error when trying to set permission read level access of all custom fields to permission set

Tags: apex

I am getting this error when I tried to set read access Level of all custom fields of account object to a permission set.

- Error:

Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id: : []

```
// get all api name fields
List<String> fields = new List<String>();

String type='Account';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
        fields.add(fieldName);
}

//permission set

Set<String> permissioinSetsLabels = new Set<String> {
    'BCP BDN Utilities non productive'
};

List<PermissionSet> pemissionSetList = [SELECT Id, Name, Label FROM PermissionSet WHERE Label IN :permissioinSetsLabels];
List<FieldPermissions> fpList = new List<FieldPermissions>();
String pcValue = '__pc';
Set<String> sStrings = new Set<String>(fields);
for(PermissionSet ps : pemissionSetList){

    for(String fieldsIterate: sStrings){
        if(!fieldsIterate.contains(pcValue) && fieldsIterate.contains('__c') && fieldsIterate!=NULL){
        FieldPermissions fp = new FieldPermissions();
        Boolean checkValue= fp.PermissionsRead;
        System.debug('el valor es: '+checkValue);
        if(checkValue == false){
            System.debug('ENTRO AL IF');
            fp.SobjectType = 'Account';
            fp.Field = 'Account'+'.'+fieldsIterate;
            System.debug(fieldsIterate);
            fp.PermissionsRead = true;
            fp.ParentId = ps.Id;
            fpList.add(fp);
            System.debug(fpList);
        }

        }
    }
    try{
        Set<FieldPermissions> myset = new Set<FieldPermissions>();
        List<FieldPermissions> result = new List<FieldPermissions>();
        myset.addAll(fpList);
        result.addAll(myset);
  if(!fpList.isEmpty()) insert result;
      System.debug('La lista es: '+fpList);}catch(Exception e){
          System.debug('el error es: '+e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the error.  You'll want to use `upsert` instead of `insert`.  Try the code below:

...

```
upsert result; //per david’s point you dont need to check for empty here
```

...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your response, but when I use upsert is the same error "System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []"

Comment: @PeterSmith do you have another idea?

Comment: Hmm, open developer console’s anonymous apex in a sandbox and be sure you are truly doing upsert, not insert. Upsert worked for me, but insert yields the error you cited. Beyond that I’m unsure. Be sure you download/analyze the correct log too